# Positioning columns/text paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do columns for text paragraphs, and I have found a way to do it using position: absolute, but with larger/smaller screen sizes it moves around rather, unfortunately. What is the best way to do columns? And why won't they line up in this case?

```css
.italic2{font-family: serif; color: #cc9900; font-size:18px; width: 150px;}

 .header3{font-family: helvetica; font-size:17px;     letter-spacing: 3px;}
 
 #column{
   text-align:left;
   line-height: 1.5;
   width: 35%;
      position: absolute;
 float: left; 
   left: 12%; 

}     

 #column1{
   text-align:left;
   line-height: 1.5;
   width: 35%;
    float: left; 
      position: absolute;
   left: 62%; 



}
```

```html
 <div id="header"> 
                <p><span class="italic"><i>the</i></span><span class="header1">&nbsp ENGLISH CLASS WEBSITE</span><br><br><div id="header2"> <span class="italic2"><i> Welcome to the English Class Website, English Students <img src="assets/img/smilingheart.png" height="20px" width="20px"> They say that the road to hell is paved with good intentions & if you ever feel like a lot of things are missing on this site, that it is never updated or you would rather go watch paint dry, well at least I tried. For a while. (It's in hell)</i></span></p>
            </div>
            <div id="column"><span class="textfont"><p>The English Class Website aims to assemble some of all the exciting subjects, information and materials, be it literature, films, music, TV-series, video games etc., that we already have been working with, or potentially could be working with, during our many English lessons together. It also provides tips and tricks on how to analyse different genres and types of texts as well as information on how to write essays yourself. Hopefully, it will be of use when you are getting ready for the exams. </div><div id="column1">If you are not a student and have stumbled upon this site by accident, you are of course more than welcome to browse through the contents, but please keep in mind that The English Class Website is only intended to make life easier for students and, well at least one teacher. Furthermore, if you represent any copyright institutions and feel that any, unintentional I must add, copyright infringement occurs I would much prefer to be contacted at aaa@aaa.com rather than sued.
            </div></div>
```

Argh. Why is this jsfiddle thing never working for me?

Comment: variant using columns, example - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/hahz7b8y/

Comment: It seems to do the same thing that I already did, but it is still "uneven". The right paragraph is for some reason placed one line above the left column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `column-width` to set the basic column size on the container element and allow the width + the viewport width to determine how many columns the screen will show. If you want a fixed number of columns (only 2), you can set `column-count` to set a specific number of columns and allow the width to change dynamically.

Here's an example of how to use both of them.

**Use the codepen to play with the viewport's width**
https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/OZyvRK/left

```css
.italic2 {
  font-family: serif;
  color: #cc9900;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 150px;
}

.header3 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#column {
  column-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#column-2 {
  column-count: 2;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.container {
  max-width: 70vw;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <span class="italic">
    <em>the</em>
  </span>
  <span class="header1">&nbsp ENGLISH CLASS WEBSITE</span>
  <br><br>
  <div id="header2">
    <span class="italic2">
      <em>
        Welcome to the English Class Website, English Students
        <img src="assets/img/smilingheart.png" height="20px" width="20px">
        They say that the road to hell is paved with good intentions & if you ever feel like a lot of things are missing on this site,
        that it is never updated or you would rather go watch paint dry, well at least I tried. For a while. (It's in hell)
      </em>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="column">
    <span class="textfont">
      The English Class Website aims to assemble some of all the exciting subjects,
      information and materials, be it literature, films, music, TV-series, video games etc.
      That we already have been working with, or potentially could be working with,
      during our many English lessons together. It also provides tips and tricks on how to
      analyse different genres and types of texts as well as information on how to write essays
      yourself. Hopefully, it will be of use when you are getting ready for the exams.
      If you are not a student and have stumbled upon this site by accident, you are of
      course more than welcome to browse through the contents, but please keep in mind that
      The English Class Website is only intended to make life easier for students and,
      well at least one teacher. Furthermore, if you represent any copyright institutions and
      feel that any, unintentional I must add, copyright infringement occurs I would much prefer
      to be contacted at aaa@aaa.com rather than sued.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="column-2">
    <span class="textfont">
      The English Class Website aims to assemble some of all the exciting subjects,
      information and materials, be it literature, films, music, TV-series, video games etc.
      That we already have been working with, or potentially could be working with,
      during our many English lessons together. It also provides tips and tricks on how to
      analyse different genres and types of texts as well as information on how to write essays
      yourself. Hopefully, it will be of use when you are getting ready for the exams.
      If you are not a student and have stumbled upon this site by accident, you are of
      course more than welcome to browse through the contents, but please keep in mind that
      The English Class Website is only intended to make life easier for students and,
      well at least one teacher. Furthermore, if you represent any copyright institutions and
      feel that any, unintentional I must add, copyright infringement occurs I would much prefer
      to be contacted at aaa@aaa.com rather than sued.
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`column-width` and `column-count` have good browser compatibility as of writing this answer :-)

https://caniuse.com/#search=column-width

[image]

Comment: This works, but is there anyway to adjust the spacing between the two columns?

Comment: I managed to do this with "column-gap: 40px;" in the css if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the columns won't line up is your random use of

tags.  Surrounding the text in each column with proper opening and closing p tags will straighten them out.

```
<div id="header"> 
<p><span class="italic"><i>the</i></span><span class="header1">&nbsp ENGLISH CLASS WEBSITE</span><br><br><div id="header2"> <span class="italic2"><i> Welcome to the English Class Website, English Students <img src="assets/img/smilingheart.png" height="20px" width="20px"> They say that the road to hell is paved with good intentions & if you ever feel like a lot of things are missing on this site, that it is never updated or you would rather go watch paint dry, well at least I tried. For a while. (It's in hell)</i></span></p>
</div>

<div id="column"><span class="textfont"><p>The English Class Website aims to assemble some of all the exciting subjects, information and materials, be it literature, films, music, TV-series, video games etc., that we already have been working with, or potentially could be working with, during our many English lessons together. It also provides tips and tricks on how to analyse different genres and types of texts as well as information on how to write essays yourself. Hopefully, it will be of use when you are getting ready for the exams.</p></div>

<div id="column1">
<p>If you are not a student and have stumbled upon this site by accident, you are of course more than welcome to browse through the contents, but please keep in mind that The English Class Website is only intended to make life easier for students and, well at least one teacher. Furthermore, if you represent any copyright institutions and feel that any, unintentional I must add, copyright infringement occurs I would much prefer to be contacted at aaa@aaa.com rather than sued.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kate, thanks for your respond. Your example did not straighten out the columns, but thanks for clearing up the missing tags. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Glad you got it working the way you wanted.  BTW, the p tags did straighten them out in my jsfiddle of your problem, but I was unable to share it.  You could also have just left out that one orphaned p tag, and that probably also would have fixed that.